# array_push flat array issue - need to be able to add multiple variables to the array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to add a pair of variables 'product_name' and 'photos' (which is the URL of the car photo) into an array.  I have a friend that said my efforts are failing because I am pushing into a flat array.  I've looked to see how to do this with variable pairs and am stymied.  He had suggested pushing row into $isotopecubes instead of how I have it below, but when I try I am getting null values.  I need to be able to access val.photo and val.product_name in my javascript call in my php file that references this ajax code.

Note:  if I just use:

```
array_push($isotopecubes, $row['photo']);
```

I get back the following JSON response on my console:

```
"/images/photos/cars/vw/14_Virginia_L.jpg", 
"/images/photos/cars/mazda/2013/14hybrid.jpg"
```

so I know I am reaching the database and getting the correct values.  Here is my ajax code:

```
<?php
include '../../global_config.php';
include 'config.php';
if ($_GET['action'] == 'get-images') {
    $selectSql = "SELECT product_name, photo FROM cars WHERE publish = 1;";
    $isotopecubeResult = $db->query($selectSql);
    $isotopecubes = array();
    while($isotopecubeResult->fetchInto($row, DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($isotopecubes, $row['photo'], $col['product_name']);
        // $isotopecubes = array_merge($isotopecubes, $row['photo']);
     }
    echo json_encode($isotopecubes);
}
?>
```

Comment: did you try dumping the `$row['photo']` and the `$col['product_name']` to see if you are getting any values?

Comment: Php is irrelevant here. If you could post your Ajax code and the output you get back, someone can help out here.

Comment: Where exactly is $col defined?

Comment: The answer below fixed it, with one correction...I needed to change col to row in his answer.  So the line should be:  $isotopecubes[] = array('product_name' => $row['product_name'], 'photo' => $row['photo']);

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by

```
<?php
 include '../../global_config.php';
 include 'config.php';
if ($_GET['action'] == 'get-images') {
   $selectSql = "SELECT product_name, photo FROM cars WHERE publish = 1;";
   $isotopecubeResult = $db->query($selectSql);
   $isotopecubes = array();
   while($isotopecubeResult->fetchInto($row, DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC)) {
      //array_push($isotopecubes, $row['photo'], $col['product_name']);
     // $isotopecubes = array_merge($isotopecubes, $row['photo']);
      $isotopecubes[] = array('product_name' => $row['product_name'], 'photo' => $row['photo']);
   }
   echo json_encode($isotopecubes);
}
?>
```

Now you will be able to get value through `val.product_name and val.photo`

Comment: That almost worked.  I had to change col to row and then it picked up both items.  When it was col, it was showing product_name as null.  In the console log, the result which is $isotopecubes shows correctly.  When I do parseJSON to that and display the resulting array to console, it shows as object, object, object, etc.  Is that correct?

Comment: Please paste Jquery code here. Yes it is row instead of col.

Comment: <?php
 include '../../global_config.php';
 include 'config.php';
if ($_GET['action'] == 'get-images') {
   $selectSql = "SELECT product_name, photo FROM cars WHERE publish = 1;";
   $isotopecubeResult = $db->query($selectSql);
   $isotopecubes = array();
   while($isotopecubeResult->fetchInto($row, DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC)) {
      //array_push($isotopecubes, $row['photo'], $row['product_name']);
     // $isotopecubes = array_merge($isotopecubes, $row['photo']);
      $isotopecubes[] = array('product_name' => $row['product_name'], 'photo' => $row['photo']);
   }
   echo json_encode($isotopecubes)